# how do I prove that for a recurrence relation of the form $a(2 n)=2^k a(n), a(n)=c n^{k}$ for some constant $c$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

if this is difficult, I am satisfied with an example for when $k=2$

in other words, how do I prove that for a recurrence relation of the form $a(2 n)=4 a(n), a(n)=c n^{2}$ for some constant c?

Comment: See [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site. I don't understand from your definition $a(2n)=4a(n)$ how $a(3)$ would be defined - can you explain?

Comment: If you are the person who proposed an anonymous edit to your own question, I suggest that you [merge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts.  Better yet, make the edit under the alosapien account.

Comment: You cannot prove it, because it's wrong. Consider $$a\bigl(2^r(2m+1)\bigr):=2^{kr}\qquad(r\geq0,\ m\geq0)\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is proper induction, since all odd $n$ are like base cases;

**Question**

Given $a(2n)=2^{k}a(n)$, show that $a(n) = cn^k$.

**Base Case:** $n=1$ (ish; unsure here)

$$a(1) = c$$
Use this to define $c$.

**Inductive step:** Assume $a(n) = cn^k$, show $a(2n) = c(2n)^k$. Now from the recurrence relation
$$\begin{aligned}
a(2n) &= 2^ka(n)\\
      &= 2^k cn^k\\
      &= c(2n)^k\,.
\end{aligned}
$$

This at least proves it for $n = 2^i$, $i \in \mathbb{N}_0$.